# Find files that have none of the read, write and execute permission for the group

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, find

I need to find the files that have none of the read, write and execute permission for the group in my directory.

I would need something like:

```
find -perm -o -000
```

(The above example is not working).

What's the correct usage of "find" to achieve this?

Comment: please see superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command without the `-o` option and without the `-` before bits of permission:

```
find -perm 000
```

The `-000` option means that at least these bits must be set for a file to match.